# How to create full screen window with MFC?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, mfc, visual-c++

I want to create full screen topmost (screen saver) window with MFC? How to create such full screen window in MFC? I tried to create win32 application and i am able to create fullscreen top most window but i want to create using MFC so later i can put different MFC controls on that window?

Please help me.

Thanks,
Jim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to adapt the example code here to do what you want:

[MSDN: Initializing a dialog box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644996(VS.85).aspx#init_box)

Comment: This example will definitely work for me. but for that i will have to write WndProc method. can i use WndProc with MFC dialog based application? How?

Comment: ok i got it. WndPRoc is wrapped up in MFC framework. MFC application works on Message Mapping. so i will have write code into onInitDialog routine.Am i correct?

Comment: That's correct. Do all your initialization in `OnInitDialog()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think removing the border from the dialog resource and showing the window as maximized (`ShowWindow(SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)`) should do the job.

As for topmost use the *System Modal* style in the dialog resource.

Answer (score 2):

I do it with a Dialog Box app. In the resource editor properties for the dialog resource, set Border=None and Title Bar=False to eliminate all border elements.  In OnInitDialog, use the following to resize the dialog to the entire desktop:

```
CRect rcDesktop;
rcDesktop.left = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
rcDesktop.right = rcDesktop.left + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
rcDesktop.top = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);
rcDesktop.bottom = rcDesktop.top + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
MoveWindow(rcDesktop, FALSE);
```

This code works on multiple monitors, unlike maximizing the window.

No need to worry about making the window topmost, Windows will display it on a dedicated desktop with no other windows present.

Comment: Perfect. However,If I have two monitors, but  I want to set full screen for only one monitor, how to do it? Thank in advance

Comment: @user8264 you need to get the coordinates of the monitor and use that for the MoveWindow.

Comment: @user8264: if you want to full screen on the main monitor:  
RECT rcDesktop;  
GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rcDesktop);  
MoveWindow(hWnd, rcDesktop.left, rcDesktop.top, rcDesktop.right, rcDesktop.bottom, FALSE);